# Can anybody explain GHC's definition of IO?

Tags: haskell, io, ghc

The title is pretty self-descriptive, but there's one part that caught my attention:

```
newtype IO a = IO (State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))
```

Stripping the `newtype`, we get:

```
State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #)
```

I don't know what `State#` stands for. Can we replace it with `State` like this:

```
State RealWorld -> (State RealWorld, a)
```

And can that be expressed as this, then?

```
State (State RealWorld) a
```

This particular construct caught my attention.

---

I know that conceptually,

```
type IO a  =  RealWorld -> (a, RealWorld)
```

And @R.MartinhoFernandes told me that I can actually think about that implementation as `ST RealWorld a`, but I'm just curious why the particular GHC version is written like it is.

Comment: Anything you see with `#` after the name means it's a "magic" hash, it's a built-in to GHC.  See [this recent post](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/02/primitive-haskell) for a thorough explanation of how it works, at least.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably best not to think too deeply about GHC's implementation of `IO`, because that implementation is *weird* and *shady* and works most of the time by compiler magic and luck. The broken model that GHC uses is that an `IO` action is a function from the state of the entire real world to a value paired with a new state of the entire real world. For humorous proof that this is a strange model, see the [`acme-realworld`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/acme-realworld) package.

The way this "works": Unless you import weird modules whose names start with `GHC.`, you can't ever touch any of these `State#` things. You're *only* given access to functions that deal in `IO` or `ST` and that ensure the `State#` can't be duplicated or ignored. This `State#` is threaded through the program, which ensures that the I/O primitives actually get called in the proper order. Since this is all for pretend, the `State#` is not a normal value at all—it has a width of 0, taking 0 bits.

Why does `State#` take a type argument? That's a much prettier bit of magic. `ST` uses that to force polymorphism needed to keep state threads separate. For `IO`, it's used with the special magic `RealWorld` type argument.

Comment: Hah, now I'm tempted to try acme-realworld.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the world-passing model is fundamentally broken just because it wouldn't be sound if you used internal implementation details; the same applies to many abstractions including things like Data.Map! Other languages *explicitly* use world-passing *and* expose the "worlds" to user code; they use type system features to ensure linearity, where Haskell ensures linearity by not exposing any operations that could possibly use the world non-linearly.

Comment: @Ben, it seems (to me) to make particularly little sense in the face of concurrency. It also requires some ... special care ... to prevent compiler optimizations from messing things up badly

Comment: @dfeuer You can make the interpretation work for concurrency (which is always; the concurrency of your program isn't relevant because the world is concurrent) by remembering that the world returned from an IO-primitive includes *arbitrary* changes (from the point of view of the pure model), not just the ones the primitive makes. But this is exactly the same as the "description-of-an-action" model of IO; the changes in the real mutable world are arbitrary and unspecified by the `main` program. Either way you need to turn to operational semantics to really say anything about what's going on.

Comment: @dfeur I do actually prefer the "description-of-an-action" model for IO. But  I think the world-passing is a perfectly serviceable interpretation. They're both easier to come at from different starting points (world passing is easy to understand if you're down with state monads, actions are more intuitive if you like meta-programming). Claims that world-passing is a broken *model* (as opposed to that it has an annoying implementation in GHC) seem inconsistent with other languages using it explicitly and still having sound declarative semantics.

Comment: @Ben, a *practical* problem with world passing is that the compiler and libraries to be extremely conservative about inlining and reordering around `IO` actions to avoid performing real-world effects in the wrong order. This has proven to be a subtle and somewhat error-prone discipline, I believe, even as it seems to prevent some valid transformations. Operational monads and similar approaches keep the lines much clearer for much longer.

Comment: I don't really know anything about linear types, but it sounds like they at least have a smaller trusted base in this regard.

Comment: @Ben, I know it's been a while... The state passing model doesn't work well with strictness analysis. What is `print 'a' >> undefined`? According to state passing, it's `_|_`. But we *definitely* want to print before throwing the exception! State passing gives no way to distinguish.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm not an expert, but I don't know of any purely declarative model that can really explain what the observable effects of that program are. All ⟂ are indistinguishable in the pure model. In the description-of-an-action model of IO we know `print 'a' >> undefined` is a program that is ⟂, so what happens when we execute that program outside our pure world of Haskell? We still don't know without turning to the operational semantics of impure `IO` execution, just as world-passing doesn't tell us what happens when `print 'a'` passes its output world to `undefined`.

Comment: @dfeur As far as I've ever seen, details such as the outside observable effects of a program that isn't well defined are *always* in how the pure model is arranged to correspond to the impure real world; choice of model doesn't save you from it. But I'm very willing to be convinced! If I understood a pure model of IO that did fully capture those sorts of details, I'd almost certainly switch to believing that is the "right" way to think about IO, rather than believing that there are a variety of equivalent ways.

Comment: @Ben, `print 'a' >> undefined` is *not* bottom in any reasonably realistic model. It's partially defined: a program that definitely prints something before failing in a way we don't allow ourselves to worry too much about.

Comment: @Ben, the state-passing model doesn't even know how to deal with infinite, but entirely well-defined, I/O actions. It can't distinguish between `fix (print 'a' >>)` and bottom. The description-of-an-action "model" (to the extent it can meaningfully be called that, being pretty much trivial) has neither problem.

Comment: @dfeuer Isn't `>>` for `IO` strict? If it's strict, then applying it to a bottom value is bottom by definition. But *operationally* we distinguish bottoms and care about how different ones behave; i.e. we care whether `error "message"` writes `message` to the console before it aborts the program, even though in the pure model of how Haskell works `error "message"` and `let loop = loop in loop` are both indistinguishable bottoms. I don't see anything different about `print 'a' >> undefined` or `fix (print 'a' >>)`. Denotationally they are bottom, operationally we care about what they do.

Comment: @Ben, it's strict in its first argument, but lazy in its second. `m >>= f` performs `m` (potentially causing observable effects) and only then calculates (and performs) the action described by applying `f` to its result. TBF, GHC has not historically been entirely consistent about this, but some people (like me) consider that a bug. `fix (print 'a' >>)` seems to be pretty universally considered non-bottom.

Comment: @Ben, sending all non-terminating I/O to bottom is a valid semantic choice, of course, but I think a bad one. I/O seems naturally coinductive.

Comment: Note that `ST s`,  on the other hand, has a conceptually *strict* bind. If it ever hits bottom, its whole history is wiped. (If you ignore the somewhat shady existence of `stToIO`).

Answer (score 2):

So in practice, an `IO x` is just some program (i.e. a schedule of CPU instructions, interrupts, whatever) which, when it's done executing, hands us a Haskell data structure of type `x`. The way that Haskell I/O works is by saying, "we will (functionally) describe how to construct the program which does stuff, and then GHC will do its thing, you'll *get* that program, and then it's up to you to actually *run* it." The resulting program basically looks like an interleaving:

```
[IO stuff] -> [Haskell code] -> [IO stuff] -> ...
```

and it's written functionally as a composition of a bunch of purely functional `[Haskell code] -> [IO stuff]` blocks.

Now, how can we *model* this with a real type class? One clever way is to accumulate all of the commands that you can send to the underlying OS as `Request` data structures, and the responses that the OS can send back as `Response` data structures. You can then model those blocks as functions between a list of requests and a list of responses. Here's a simple version of that model, heavily exploiting laziness:

```
type IO x = [Response] -> ([Request], x)
```

The OS now provides this function with a lazy list -- don't call the head of it just yet, you have to first cons something onto the outgoing requests! -- and you produce this pair of a lazy list of requests and a lazy result. The OS reads your first request, does it, and provides the result as the first element of the Response. In this way you sort of get a fixed point operator. Now we see what `return` and `bind` look like:

```
 -- return needs to yield a special symbol of type Request which stops the 
 -- process of querying the OS.
 return x = ([Done], x) 

 -- bind needs to split the responses between those fed to mx and the rest,
 -- assume that every request yields exactly one response  so we can examine
 -- just the length of x_requests.
 bind :: ([Response] -> ([Request], x)) -> 
         (x -> [Response] -> ([Request], y)) -> 
         [Response] -> ([Request], y)
 bind mx x_to_my responses = (init x_requests ++ y_requests, y)
     where (x_requests, x) = mx responses
           (y_requests, y) = x_to_my x $ drop (length x_requests - 1) responses
```

This should be *correct* but it's a little *confusing*. A little less confusing is to imagine a state monad with "the real world" inside, but unfortunately that is *incorrect*:

```
newtype IO x = RawIO (runIO :: RealWorld -> (RealWorld, x))
```

What's wrong with this? Basically it's the fact that the original RealWorld persists. We might for example write:

```
RawIO $ \world -> let (world1, x) = runIO (putStrLn "Name?" >> getLine) world
                      (world2, y) = runIO (putStrLn "Age?" >> getLine) world
                  in (world1, y)
```

What does this do? It performs the computation in a branching universe: in world #1 it asks one question (Name?) and in world #2 it asks a different question (Age?). It then throws world #2 away, but keeps the answer that it got there.

So we are living in world #1, it asks us our name, and then magically it knows our age. The side effect from world #2 (asking us our age) cannot happen due to referential transparency), but the result of it has been acquired. Whoops -- real I/O can't do that.

Well, that's OK as long as we hide the `RawIO` constructor! We'll just make all of *our* functions well-behaved and be done with it. We can then write completely sane versions of bind and return:

```
return x = RawIO $ \world -> (world, x)
bind mx x_to_my = RawIO $ \world -> let (world', x) = runIO mx world in 
    runIO (x_to_my x) world'
```

So when we introduce side-effectful functions into the language, we can just write them a wrapper which ignores the "world" argument and performs the side-effect when the function is run. We then have:

```
unsafePerformIO mx = let (_, x) = runIO mx (error "RealWorld doesn't exist) in x
```

which can perform these I/O operations when GHC/GHCi *actually* needs them to happen.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody explain GHC's definition of `IO`?

It's based on the *pass-the-planet* model of I/O:

> *An `IO` computation is a function that (logically) takes the state of the world, and returns a modified world as well as the return value. Of course, GHC does not actually pass the world around; instead, it passes a dummy “token”, to ensure proper sequencing of actions in the presence of lazy evaluation, and performs input and output as actual side effects!*

(from [A History of Haskell](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.168.4008&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Paul Hudak, John Hughes, Simon Peyton Jones and Philip Wadler; page 26 of 55.)

Using that description as a guide:

```
newtype IO a   =  IO (FauxWorld -> (# FauxWorld, a #))
```

where:

```
type FauxWorld =  State# RealWorld
```

Why bother with bulky world-values when the I/O model provides the option for using side-effects diligently?

> *[...] a machinery whose most eminent characteristic is state [means] the gap between model and machinery is wide, and therefore costly to bridge. [...]
>
> This has in due time also been recognized by the protagonists of functional
> languages.[...]*
>
> [Niklaus Wirth.](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/wirth/Articles/GoodIdeas_origFig.pdf)

Now that we're on the topic of implementation details:

> I'm just curious as to why the particular GHC version is written like it is?

It's primarily to avoid gratuitous runtime evaluation and heap usage:

- `State# RealWorld` and the unboxed tuple `(# ..., ... #)` are *unlifted types* - in GHC, they don't take up space in the heap. Being unlifted also means they can be used immediately without prior evaluation.
- The use of `State#` to define `IO` (rather than using a world-type directly)
  reduces `RealWorld` to an abstract tag-type:

  ```
  type ST# s a   =  State# s -> (# State# s, a #)

  newtype IO a   =  IO (ST# RealWorld a)
  ```

  `ST#` can then be reused elsewhere:

  ```
  newtype ST s a =  ST (ST# s a)
  ```

  For more information, see John Launchbury and Simon Peyton Jones's [State in Haskell](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.52.3656&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

The `Realworld` and unlifted types are both GHC-specific extensions.